# short story about mars colony vote influenced by French sounding song

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find a short story that I read recently in an SF compendium so probably written not so recently. Possibly Asimov, but not sure.

The story centres around Mars colonists having to vote on a topic. I think it was whether to allow Earth to mine Mars. There are two camps, the 'yes' and the 'no'.

One group has a catchy jingle and looks likely to win the vote. The other group uses a seemingly unconnected song. In the end, they win because their song sounds like something in French and all the colonists subconsciously understand the message, as they originated from France

The whole story seemed contrived just to make an awful pun but I can't remember more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds to me like Asimov's "[Battle-Hymn](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?72835)", included in his posthumous collection *[Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(Asimov_book))*.

According to [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Creator/IsaacAsimov) (which has no separate work page for it, but scroll down to the entry for "Feghoot") the story is about a vote whether or not to allow hyperspace experiments to take place on Mars. The "Yes" faction wins by using the French national anthem, *La Marseillaise*, which succeeds because it sounds like "Mars say 'Yes'". (There's your awful pun for you.)

[This answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/2883) over on Literature.SE expounds on Asimov's fondness for short stories contrived to make awful puns and includes "Battle-Hymn" as an example, as does the Wikipedia article on [feghoots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feghoot).

Comment: I dug the book out and checked. You are 100% correct. No thanks for reminding me of that awful, awful story though :)

Comment: @OrganicMarble Better you than me! My searching didn't lead me to the actual text itself (or I would've linked it), but from the sound of it, I'm not missing much.

Comment: I'm a big fan of a lot of his writing, but not these stories-than-exist-to-drop-a-bad-pun.